# Multiboot problem with windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I installed Ubuntu along with windows 8.1. After installation when i started the pc without showing boot menu it directly boot to windows. Then i booted from linux live cd and installed  boot-repair and repaired. After that it only showing the ubuntu option boot menu please help me.
report from boot-repair in following URL

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12733723/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enter terminal `Alt + Ctrl + F2`.
2. Do `update-grub`.

Those steps will automatically update your grub if windows boot partition is not corrupt.

Comment: Thanks bro. it worked.. Is there any way to change the order of os is  boot menu..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using 3rd party tools like boot-repair does not work perfectly.
Reinstall GRUB bootloader to your Ubuntu installation with a built-in tool.

Boot from the Ubuntu install media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda3` = system partition - (taken from pastebin output).

Boot into your Ubuntu installation, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now all detected operating systems should appear in the GRUB boot menu.